Asking question about RSA on Stackexchange
There is an explanation of math behind the RSA on:
What is the relation between RSA & Fermat's little theorem?
It is answered by Antony Vennard. It looks very interesting, but unfortunately Antony is not defining many of the terms. 
I would like to have a place where I can ask additional questions regarding Antony's answer and get clarification from either him, or anyone else who knows the subject.
I wrote my question in the answer field, and it was deleted.
But I could not find a field or asking related questions.
I don't want to ask a new question, because my question is about the existing answer.
For example I'd like to know how the definition of ϕ(p,q).
He is only defining ϕ(p), but not ϕ of a set of a pair of numbers.
This is just one example.
Ideally I'd like to see the explanation with examples of concrete numbers used, and how it relates to cryptography.

Welcome to Crypto.StackExchange, Veet!  I'm afraid posting a new question is not the way to do it; if you don't delete this question yourself, it will likely be deleted soon.  Questions here need to be self-contained.  Once you gain a bit more reputation, you can post a comment below Antony's answer.  Or, if you can formulate a self-contained question that is of interest in its own right, you can post a separate question.  Make sure to read the [FAQ] first.  In this case, any good textbook that describes RSA will answer your question about the definition of $\phi(pq)$.

I'm pretty sure that it's a typo for ϕ(pq) (ϕ applied to the product). That's what the definition calls for.

Unfortunately you don't have enough rep points to comment. To see how rep points translate to privileges see here. That would be a good way to go about seeking clarification. As DW says, however, many of your questions will be answered in a good textbook.
